# How to do one-one mapping between 2 tables having composite key in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sybase, one-to-one, joincolumn

I have 2 tables vanTb and vanSiteTb. The primary key for vanTb is vId. The vanSiteTb has a composite primary key of 2 columns viz. vNum and vSiteC.

The vanTb have also 2 columns vNum and vSiteC.

There is a one to one relation between these 2 tables.

The database schema is from a legacy database, so it cannot be changed.

In hibernate, I have defined 2 entity beans viz. VanTb.java and VanSiteTb.java.

For VanSiteTb.java, I have defined a new java class using @Embeddable. This class's object is defined in VanSiteTb.java using @EmbeddedId.

Now, I want to define a one-one relationship between these 2 tables.

So,

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "<name>", schema = "<name>")
    public class vanTb implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="vId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int vId;



    @Column(name="vNum", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String vNum;

    @Column(name="vSiteC", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String vSiteC;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(???)
    private vanSiteTb v;

    }

@Embeddable
public class PmKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "vNum", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String vNum;

    @Column(name = "vSiteC", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String vsiteC;

    ....
    getter and setter for both properties.
...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = ".vSiteTb", schema="")
public class vSiteTb implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PmKey pmKey;

    @Column(name = "vNum", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String vNum;

    @Column(name = "vSiteC", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String vSiteC;

    public PmKey getPmKey() {
        return pmKey ;
    }

    public void setPmKey (PmKey pmKey ) {
        this.pmKey = pmKey ;
    }

    public String getVNum() {
        return vNum;
    }

    public void setVNum(String vNum) {
        this.vNum = vNum;
    }

    public String getVSiteC() {
        return vSiteC;
    }

    public void setVSiteC(String vSiteC) {
        this.vSiteC = vSiteC;
    }

}
```

Now to define one-one relationship, I have to write @OneToOne in JPA, but what should be written for @JoinColumn, where I have mentioned ???.

To identify a unique entry from both tables, we should have vNum and vSite of both tables should match with each other.

```
select * from vanTb v, vSiteTb site where 
v.vNum = site.vNum and v.SiteC = site.SiteC
and v.vId = 1234
```

The above query will return a unique row from both tables.

Please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the `@OneToOne` join columns inside `vanTb` to `vanSiteTb`, it would be:

```
@JoinColumns({
  @JoinColumn(name = "vNum", referencedColumnName = "vNum"),
  @JoinColumn(name = "vSiteC", referencedColumnName = "vSiteC")
})
```

If you had a column for the `vanTab`'s primary key `vId` in `vanSiteTb`, you would map the inverse of that back to the `vanTab` like this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "vId", referencedColumnName = "vId")
```

Just remember that `name` represents the column name in the current table of the entity where you're adding the join column annotation and that `referencedColumnName` represents the name of the column in the associated entity's table.

Comment: Do I also need to write @OneToOne in vanSiteTb ? If yes, then I also to define a property vanTb in vanSiteTb entity bean, right?

Comment: There is no requirement to place a `@OneToOne` inside `vanSiteTb` unless you need to traverse back to `vanTb` through the object graph.